# does kaspersky support command line interface?

Tags: anti-virus

kaspersky support command line interface yes or no (or how i can control with kaspersky by command line interface) ... and how i can use it to scan some file on AIX server UNIX operating system ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it does support a command line interface. You can find more about how to do this [**here**](http://support.kaspersky.com/faq/?qid=208280694).

To scan a file on you AIX system you will need to get your AIX system to share some portion of it's filsystem in a manner that your windows system can read. Answers to another of your questions provide ths information.

EDIT:

To test

First uncheck the `Select action automatically` in the `Interactive protection` section of the Kapersky `General Settings` and click apply.

Now create a copy of the [**eicar**](http://support.kaspersky.com/faq/?qid=193238512) test virus in a suitable location e.g at the windows command line.

```
mkdir c:\temp
copy con c:\temp\test.com
paste the test virus code from the instructions above here
^Z
```

Your Kapersky real time scanner will probably pop up and ask you what to do select Block

Now to test avp - back to the command line

```
avp scan c:\temp /i9
```

lots of output here

Select S

more output

```
echo %errorlevel%
```

102

Now repeat the above avp command  and select D then L instead of S (this will delete the test file)

```
echo %errorlevel%
```

101

Again repeat the above avp command

```
echo %errorlevel%
```

0

Comment: thanks lain ... i want to ask you in kaspersky the Return codes of the anti-virus scan tasks .... is `101 and 101` ... where this value hold and how i can get it .... i use `%ERRORLEVEL%` but the resut `0` ???

Comment: The 101 and 102 exit codes are only returned when working with or having detected dangerous objects. A 0 code is an indication of success.

Comment: please i want to test this option i don't know ... please if you know tell me ... becuse i want to write bash file and use this value .